# Bootstrap navbar href to another page does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, href, navbar

li href with '#' works fine but I'd like to write url of the another page. I tried to add some divs, forms or btn from bootstrap but that solution makes my page messy(unexpected margins or something strange).

I have no idea how to solve the problem.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="2s">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <!-- Sklep -->
        <li><a href="http://www.ebay.com">Sklep</a>
        </li>


        <!-- SOCIAL -->
        <li style="padding-top:9px; margin-left:50px;">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="blank" style="padding:0 5px;  margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto;" class="social">
            <img src="img/ikony/facebook-2-32.png" alt="">
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="blank" style="padding:0 5px;  margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto;" class="social">
            <img src="img/ikony/youtube-2-32.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: It seems to be working on my PC, ...

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Which links don't work? The facebook/youtube links? How don't they work?

Comment: `target="blank"` should be `target="_blank"`, unless you have a target "blank" defined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question, however when I have formatting issues with href tags, I tend to use JavaScript:

```
<div onclick="http://ebay.com" />
```

Perhaps if you explain your question a little better I may be able to help.

Comment: http://daniel.klikom.net/zukiemprzezswiat/

Look at this website, when you click on "sklep" in the navbar, nothing happens. I have no idea how to fix it.